# The country drop down list for agent model is not being created

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to add a country drop down list to my agent form, the database part has been created when running the migration but when I generate the controllers and the views, the drop down list won't generate

```
public class Agent
    {
        public int AgentID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Social Insurance Number")]
        public string SIN { get; set; }
        public Country Country { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "First Name cannot be longer than 20 characters")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Country
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Country")]
        public countries Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Agent> Agents { get; set; }
    }

    public enum countries
    {
        canada,
        usa
    }
```

Comment: Please post relevant code that generates the drop down list.

Comment: the country class should be the drop down list